# retrieve ngrams in solr for a particular word

Tags: solr

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="5" minShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="5" minShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true"/>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I am using the ShingleFilterFactory to create ngrams. Now i want to retrive all the ngrams for a particular word.
Suppose i entered "night" then i want all the ngrams with the word night.

right now i am getting the only the top results from all the ngrams from my documents with the below query:

```
http://localhost/solr/admin/luke?fl=text&numTerms=50000&wt=json
```

Comment: All ngrams generated from the word "night", all ngrams generated from a word starting with "night" in the index or all ngrams from words indexed that contain "night" somewhere in it? Or all words that generated the ngram "night"?

Comment: all ngrams from words indexed that contain night